# Word mail merge: Show only the Nth row of a table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

How do I show only the Nth row of a table in a Word mail-merge?

My template is of this format:

```
{ MERGEFIELD TableStart:widgetList }

Foo: { MERGEFIELD foo }
Bar: { MERGEFIELD bar }

{ MERGEFIELD TableEnd:widgetList }
```

But I only want to see `Foo` and `Bar` for the Nth widget in the list. How would I limit the output to just that row of the `widgetList` table? Specifically, I need the last row.

I can't do anything clever with macros, or anything like that - I'm constrained to uploading an unadorned .docx with merge fields into Proprietary SystemⓇ, which will then spit out reports on request.

Relatedly:

- the example template from Proprietary SystemⓇ uses this syntax:

  `{ MERGEFIELD widgetList!size }`

  to show the number of rows in the table. Is this standard Word behaviour, and is `size` the only keyword which can follow the `!`? I tried to find documentation but my google-fu is weak today.
- can I sort the table at the mail-merge point, or must that be done upstream? I'd like to reverse the table if I can't restrict it to the last row only.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `TableStart:`, `TableEnd:` and `!size` are all extensions provided by Proprietary SystemⓇ so I'll need to ask them for help. C'est la vie.